# Create common keydown function with ID/Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

While working on Compliance for the buttons clicks, I happen to add several keydown events but with different classes and ID's triggering the onclick inside the condition if pressed Enter Key. I want to put all of the several methods under one function and re-use that

```
               $(".classOne").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        hideShow('classOne');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                $("#iDOne").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        navigateTo('somepage');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                $(".classTwo").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        $(".classTwo").trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                $(".classThree").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        navigateTo('anotherpage');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                $(".classFour").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        $(".classFour").trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                $("#idTwo").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        $("#idTwo").trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

I'm learning to write functions etc, so pardon my novice-ness here

```
    $(".targetClass").keydown(function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        //  do the click/navigate/showhide...
        }
     });
```

targetClass being changed to the clicked element/ID

How can I do  something like above, re-using the same method while passing the ID/Class(whichever is on the html element) and trigger the onclick and avoid writing same functions numerous times?
Thank you in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your click operations seem to fall into a number of categories.  If you add the operation to the element, then your code can determine what to do without knowing what that actual element is, eg:

```
<button type="button" data-operation="click">click</button>
<button type="button" data-operation="navigate" data-navigate="anotherpage">another page</button>
```

You *could* then handle these in a single function:

```
$(".targetClass").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
       switch ($(this).data("operation")) {
           case "click":
               $(this).trigger("click")
               return false;
           case "navigate":
               navigateTo($(this).data("navigate"));
               return false;
```

or (preferred) you could then add handlers per operation:

```
$(".targetClass[data-operation=click]").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});

$(".targetClass[data-operation=navigate]").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        navigateTo($(this).data("navigate"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Depending on the operations, and your preference, you can use classes for these (which may be more efficient for the selector, not tested, possibly micro-optimisation), eg:

```
<button type="button" class="targetClass trigger-click">click</button>
<button type="button" class="targetClass trigger-navigate" data-navigate="anotherpage">another page</button>
```

then similar split event handlers:

```
$(".targetClass.trigger-click").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});

$(".targetClass.trigger-navigate").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        navigateTo($(this).data("navigate"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Using separate handlers means extending to new functionality will less likely affect existing code (ie improved maintainability).  If you want to add a new operation:

```
$(".targetClass.trigger-show").click(function() {
    $($(this).data("trigger")).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this

```js
    function KeyDown(ele, type) {
      var $selector = null;
      if (type == 'cssClass') {
        $selector = $("." + ele);
        else if (type == "id")
          $selector = $("#" + ele);
      }

      $selctor.on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          switch (ele)
          case "classOne":
            hideShow('classOne');
            return false;
            break;
          case "iDOne":
            navigateTo('somepage');
            break;
          case "classTwo":
            $(".classTwo").trigger("click");
            break;
          case "classThree":
            navigateTo('anotherpage');
            break;
          case "classFour":
            $(".classFour").trigger("click");
            break;
          case "idTwo":
            $("#idTwo").trigger("click");
            break;

            return false;
        }
      })
      
$(function(){
      KeyDown('classOne', 'cssClass');
      KeyDown('iDOne', 'id') ;
      KeyDown('classTwo', 'cssClass');
      KeyDown('classThree', 'cssClass');
      KeyDown('classFour', 'cssClass');
      KeyDown('idTwo', 'id') ;

})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sagar. This partially works as the keydown function is triggering only after few clicks. It's not working on first click of the element.

Comment: Did you initialize it for each DOM? Above is just example and I have initialized event just for  `classOne` and  `idTwo`.

Comment: Yes, i have added it in the html element. <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="classOne" onclick="navigate('home') onkeydown="Keydown('classOnce', 'cssClass')>...</div>

Comment: No. You initializing it in `onkeydown` event itself. Initialize it in `onload` function. Please look at updated answer. Remove `onkeydown` in the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of an array of the attributes to loop through them:

```js
var elList = [".classOne","#iDOne",".classTwo",".classThree",".classFour","#idTwo"];

elList.forEach(function(el){
  $(el).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if($(this).hasClass('classOne')){
        //do your staff
        console.log('classOne');
      }
      else if($(this).attr('id') == 'iDOne'){
        //do your staff
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      }
      //do it for all
      //
      //
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="classOne" >classOne
<input id="iDOne">iDOne
```